# In Google Sheets, what formula would let me check if all rows that have a given value in one column also have a specific value in another?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

[Example Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1I244H6XqxvyDtnA4Xr78HDqS7sSOgtRPYGAbB330MLE/edit?usp=sharing)

I have a set of tasks with an arbitrary number of subtasks listed on Sheet1. I want the simple list of tasks on Sheet2 to indicate accurately which ones have all subtasks completed. What formula should I use to do this?

I am thinking some version of COUNTIFS, but I am not sure how to formulate it into an IF formula.

Comment: If I understood your concern correctly, it will only be TRUE if all the conditions from the other sheet are all checked and FALSE if not. I have suggested a solution using `QUERY()` and `AND()`. Let me know if this answers your question.

Answer (score 1):

You need logical `AND()` operation. Try with `MAP()` and `FILTER()`.

```
=MAP(A2:A5,LAMBDA(x,AND(FILTER(Sheet1!B2:B,Sheet1!A2:A=x))))
```

TO refer full column as input for large and growing dataset, try-

```
=MAP(A2:INDEX(A2:A,COUNTA(A2:A)),LAMBDA(x,AND(FILTER(Sheet1!B2:B,Sheet1!A2:A=x))))
```

[image]

Comment: What does Lambda do in this formula? I don't think I have used that before.

Comment: Google releases a set of new formulas which is familiar as `LAMBDA()` helper formulas. MAP, BYROW, MAKEARRAY, SCAN, REDUCE and few more... Please do a google search for more info.

Answer (score 0):

One way to approach this is:

1. FILTER to collect the result of every matching T/F
2. IF statement to set the cell to either 1 or 0 depending on the T/F
3. ARRAYFORMULA to wrap the previous equations to allow for multi-cell output
4. PRODUCT to return 1 if all instances are TRUE or 0 if one or more instances are FALSE.

   ```
   =PRODUCT(ARRAYFORMULA(IF(FILTER(Sheet1!B2:B9, Sheet1!A2:A9=A2)=TRUE, 1, 0)))
   ```

Additionally the equation can be wrapped in another IF statement to modify the output type. i.e (1,0), (TRUE,FALSE), (RED,YELLOW), etc.

Answer (score 0):

**Try:**

```
=AND(QUERY(Sheet1!$A$2:$B$9,"Select B where A = '"&A2&"'"))
```

Drag down below.

**Result:**
[image]

**Explanation:**

Using `QUERY()` to get all the data from Column A
[image]

You then modify this to only return TRUE or FALSE which is in Column B.
[image]

You then add the wrap it with `AND()` which will return TRUE if all conditions are true, and FALSE if at least one is false.